# Is there any "proper" way of setting the viewport for QGis Time Manager?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, image, timemanager

I'm working on video visualisation for some geo data. Everything works fine for me except the viewport that the time manager plugin is using for image frames. It makes image frames size of actual map window size which is something like 1248x636 in my case now. When I resize the QGIS window the time manager plugin starts exporting image frames of different size.

Is there any "proper" way of setting the viewport so I don't have to play around with application window size? Or should I perhaps bulk edit (crop?) all the frame images before merging them with mencoder?

I'm using Quantum GIS 1.8.0 with Time Manager 0.7

Comment: I forgot to add that my goal is to make a 720p (1280x720) video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "proper" way to set the frame size. Bulk cropping sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Ok, thank you for quick reply. Thanks for this great qgis plugin btw!